# Alternative for ansible lookups as it always looks up files on localhost

Tags: file, ubuntu, ansible, terraform, lookup

I am running an ansible playbook inside a terraform `local-exec` provisioner with inline inventory of the remote instance IP.

```
- name: Install git
  apt:
    name: git
    state: present
    update_cache: yes

- name: Clone the git repository
  become_user: "{{ SSH_USER }}"
  git:
    repo: "{{ REPO_URL }}"
    dest: "{{ SRC_DIR }}"

- name : Find files with .pub extension
  become_user: "{{ SSH_USER }}"
  find:
    paths: "{{ SRC_DIR }}"
    patterns: '*.pub'
  register: pub_files

- name: Append the content of all public key files to authorized_keys file.
  become_user: "{{ SSH_USER }}"
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ DEST_FILE }}"
    line: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ item.path }}') }}"
    insertafter: EOF
    create: "yes"
    state: present
# loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', "{{ SRC_DIR }}/*.pub", wantlist=True) }}"
# with_fileglob: "{{ SRC_DIR }}/*.pub"
  with_items: "{{ pub_files.files }}"      
    
- name: Display destinationFile contents
  become_user: "{{ SSH_USER }}"
  command: cat "{{ DEST_FILE }}"
  register: command_output

- name: Print to console
  become_user: "{{ SSH_USER }}"
  debug:
    msg: "{{command_output.stdout}}"
```

The ansible playbook should clone a git repo and copies the content of it's files to another file.
But when using [ansible lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html) to read the content of the files (which are cloned in remote host), it always looks for the file in localhost.

> Like all templating, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible
> control machine.

Thus the above given playbook fails with error:

```
No such file or directory found
```

The similar issue occurred when used `with_fileglob` and `loop` with fileglob lookup to iterate over the files, as they also does a lookup inside. I replaced that with `find` module to list files names, `register` it in a variable and then iterate over it in next step using `with_items`.

Is there any such alternative to read content of files?

Comment: It looks like your playbook already has a task to read the content of a remote file ("Display destinationFile contents"). You're getting the content of a remote file and placing it into a variable (`command_output.stdout`). Isn't that exactly what you're asking about?

Comment: @larsks Yes, i tried that way. But accessing the cat output from the registered variable was not working for me properly.

Comment: Your answer ("It worked as i did it using cat") appear to contradict that comment...

Comment: @larsks Sorry, Actually it was not a problem with cat. I was not properly filtering out the public key content from the variable file_content. When i corrected that, cat method worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked as i did it using `cat`.

```
- name: Install git
  become_user: root
  apt:
    name: git
    state: present
    update_cache: yes   

- name: Clone the git repository
  git:
    repo: "{{ REPO_URL }}"
    dest: "{{ SRC_DIR }}"

- name : Find file names with .pub extension
  find:
    paths: "{{ SRC_DIR }}"
    patterns: '*.pub'
  register: pub_files 
 
- name: Get contents of all those .pub files
  shell: cat {{ item.path }}
  register: file_content
  with_items: "{{ pub_files.files }}" 

- name: Print file_content to console
  debug:
    var: item.stdout
  with_items:
    - "{{ file_content.results }}"

- name: Append the content of all public key files to authorized_keys file.
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ DEST_FILE }}"
    line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    insertafter: EOF
    create: "yes"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - "{{ file_content.results }}"   
    
- name: Display destinationFile contents
  command: cat "{{ DEST_FILE }}"
  register: command_output

- name: Print to console
  debug:
    msg: "{{command_output.stdout}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetching them back to the ansible control node first works. And note that ansible has an authorized_keys module that simplifies the task of adding the keys.

```
  tasks:
  - name: find all the .pub files
    find: 
      paths: "/path/remote"
      recurse: no
      patterns: "*.pub"
    register: files_to_fetch
  - debug:
      var: files_to_fetch.files

  - name: "fetch .pub files from remote host"
    fetch: 
      flat: yes
      src:  "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: ./local/
    with_items: "{{ files_to_fetch.files }}"

  - name: update SSH keys
    authorized_key:
     user: user1
     key: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
     state: present
     #exclusive: yes
    with_fileglob:
      - local/*.pub
```